# Android Changing Appname in strings.xml through gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to change the app_name in strings.xml through gradle script. I am using Eclipse therefore I cannot create different folder structure to define different strings.xml files at this point. i have written the following script,

```
task changeAppNameForBuildType01AndBuildType02 << {

    println "Changing application name in strings.xml"

    println "App name will be changed to ${applicationName}."

    File stringsXmlFile = new File("res/values/strings.xml")
    String contents = stringsXmlFile.getText()
    stringsXmlFile.setText(contents.replaceAll("<string name=\"app_name\">[^<]*</string>", "<string name=\"app_name\">${applicationName}</string>"))

}

task changeAppNameForLiveBuild << {

    println "Changing application name in strings.xml"

    println "App name will be changed to AppName."
    File stringsXmlFile = new File("res/values/strings.xml")
    String contents = stringsXmlFile.getText()
    stringsXmlFile.setText(contents.replaceAll("<string name=\"app_name\">[^<]*</string>", "<string name=\"app_name\">AppName</string>"))

}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'processReleaseManifest') {
        task.dependsOn stripResources
    }

    /*if (task.name == 'preDexBuildType01' || task.name == 'preDexBuildType02' ) {
        task.dependsOn changeAppNameForBuildType01AndBuildType02
    }*/

    if (task.name == 'preDexRelease') {
        task.dependsOn changeAppNameForLiveBuild
    } else {
        task.dependsOn changeAppNameForBuildType01AndBuildType02
    }
}
```

This script only works for BuildType01 but it does not change the appname for BuildType02 or Release. Can anyone please help me fix this. Why wouldn't it work? Thanks!